# Return a record based on multiple criteria including time in a military format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, timestamp

MS Office Professional Plus 2016

Need to return a value from column C using multiple criteria:

- Criteria (column D) should be 1
- Date (column A) should be the latest
- Time (column B) should be the latest

| # | Date (A) | Time (B) | VALUE TO RETURN (C) | Criteria (D) | *Helper (E) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/30/2020 | 1345 | Ar | 1 | 12/30/20 13:45:00 |
| 2 | 12/30/2020 | 1100 | Ka | 1 | 12/30/20 11:00:00 |
| 3 | 12/30/2020 | 1720 | La | 0 | 12/30/20 17:20:00 |
| 4 | 12/30/2020 | 900 | Em | 1 | 12/30/20 09:00:00 |
| 5 | 12/31/2020 | 100 | Zo | 1 | 12/31/20 01:00:00 |
| 6 | 12/31/2020 | 1320 | Cy | 0 | 12/31/20 13:20:00 |
| 7 | 12/31/2020 | 700 | Pi | 1 | 12/31/20 07:00:00 |
| 8 | 12/31/2020 | 1830 | Be | 0 | 12/31/20 18:30:00 |

The result should be: Pi (12/31/2020 at 700 with 1 in column D)

Steps made:

- Created a helper column (E) with a timestamp: `=TEXT(A1,"m/dd/yy ")&TEXT(TEXT(B1,"00\:00")+0,"hh:mm:ss")`
- Tried one option to get the value from column C: `{=INDEX(C1:C8,MATCH(MAX(INDEX((D1:D8=1)*E1:E8,)),DATEVALUE(E1:E8),0))}`

Unfortunately, can't make the last array formula work properly.

Any help with the formula or any other ideas or ways to return the Value from column C would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found one solution, not a pretty one but it works for now:

```
{=INDEX(C1:C8,MATCH(MAX(INDEX((D1:D8=1)*E1:E8,)),DATEVALUE(E1:E8)+TIMEVALUE(E1:E8),0))}
```

Still would be grateful to see other, more efficient, options.